# What is the difference between 싸우다 and 싸움하다?

Tags: vocabulary, difference

Both are translated as fight, struggle. Can both be used to mean "quarrel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use word '싸움하다'.

I don't know explanation below is correct, but here's why:

'-하다' makes noun to verb. (Like 결혼(marriage) - 결혼하다(marry)). But noun 싸움 is word came from verb 싸우다.

So use '싸우다', not '싸움하다'.